# Underscore and character condition for levels selection in regex using R

Tags: r, grepl

I'd like to remove the levels with "O", but just only after the second
underscore "_". In my example:

```
my.ds <- c("Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_2O","Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_30O",
"Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_32O","Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_33O",
"Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_34O","Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_35O",
"Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_30","Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_492",
"Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_493","Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_494")
```

My desirable output is:

```
sel.ds
[1] "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_30" "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_492" 
[2] "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_493" "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_494"
```

Please, help me.

Comment: By "O" you really mean the **number** "0" - correct?

Comment: Should it read "after 3rd underscore" instead as shown in the desired output? Would "only in last section"  work? If yes, then `grep("_[^o]+$",my.ds, ignore.case = T, value = T)` returns the same subset as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this. Remove strings with a "O" after 3 sections terminated by a "_".

```r
my.ds[!grepl("(.*_){3}.+O", my.ds)]
#> [1] "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_30"  "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_492"
#> [3] "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_493" "Novo_Oeste_CANTODOPINHE_494"
```